# How to get data from an attribute of foreign key table to primary key table in Django

Tags: django, django-models, serialization, foreign-keys

I want to get all the issues.reference with status "Exemption" in Project model's exemption field, in order to send the it as a response.
As issue model has project as a foreign key field so I can't import Issue in Project model, that leads to circular import.

**Project Model**

'''
class Project(models.Model):

```
creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
expiry_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
exemption = ListField(models.CharField(max_length=128), blank=True, null=True)
```

'''

**Issue Model**

'''
class Issue(models.Model):

```
requestor = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='issues', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
projects = models.ManyToManyField(Project, related_name='issues_projects')
reference = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True, editable=False, null=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=IssueStatus.choices, null=True)
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

In views you can simply use:

```
issue = Issue.objects.get() #your query to select the issue 
issue_project = issue.projects

#say you want to creation_date from above selected project.
creation_date = issue_project.creation_date 

# and so on
```

Comment: This will not work for me because Project is a foreign key in Issue and if I try to access the Issue model in the Project model file. It gives an import error as this will be a circular import.